# Android: How to have a GridView (horizontal) adjust with 2 item and a half item

Tags: android, gridview

I want to have this kind of horizontal GridView (like Google Play). How to have 2 and a half visible items ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- Put the `GridView` into a `FrameLayout`,
- set the `layout_width` of the `GridView` to `wrap_content`, and
- set the `layout_width` of the `FrameLayout` to a `value` such that the third item in the `GridView` only appears half.

Hope it help